# How to lock all tables except some specific table?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I am trying to set a stage server which replicate some tables like articles, user etc from master. If I start the slave server as `read_only` I am not able to my stage site up because there are some tables like cache or session which needs to be rewritten.

So I am trying to use `replicate_do_table` and then locking those tables manually using below snippets and let other tables like cache and session rewritable.

In short I want `read_only` lock for all the tables in a database excluding some specific tables to read-write access.

I found below snippet on mysql website. But how can I select only specific tables without writing all the table names manually inside `LOCK TABLES`

```
LOCK TABLES
    tbl_name [[AS] alias] lock_type
    [, tbl_name [[AS] alias] lock_type] ...

lock_type: {
    READ [LOCAL]
  | [LOW_PRIORITY] WRITE
}
```

Note: I am using innodb storage engine and mariadb 10.3

Comment: Do not use `LOCK TABLES` if you are using InnoDB.  Please describe further what you are trying to do and "why".

Comment: @RickJames Thanks for having a look on my question. I have updated it. Please have a look again.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `LOCK TABLES` with InnoDB.  For this situation consider the following...

- Leave `read_only = OFF`
- Provide a readonly login for your application *when it goes to the Slave* in addition to a readwrite login for when it talks to the Master.

The app user would have grants something like:

```
GRANT SELECT         ON app_db.*   TO app_user@slave
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON sessions.* TO app_user@slave   -- and cache.*
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON app_db.*   TO app_user@master
```